# How do I make custom social buttons using JavaScript rollover images?

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, facebook-social-plugins, rollover

I wanted to make custom social buttons (with Like links to Facebook, share links to Stumbleupon, etc.) for my site. So far, I've put in a fair amount of work in Photoshop and Fireworks, but now I can't associate the required script with the hotspots on the buttons (bear in mind that I'm new to Fireworks, and I'm not sure if I should be using slices or hotspots in this case). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just use a regular hover in css. You use sprites even. Put your pictures's hover states and regular states next to each other in Photoshop and crop  and in CSS put the width and the height on your anchor tags. And, on hover, use background-position to position your picture. That's how I would do it.